# django.core.management not found on heroku push

Tags: django, heroku

im experiencing this problem when deploying my django application to heroku , it says

```
2012-03-08T06:26:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python platformsite/manage.py runserver`
2012-03-08T06:26:47+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2012-03-08T06:26:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "platformsite/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
2012-03-08T06:26:47+00:00 app[web.1]:     from django.core.management import execute_manager
2012-03-08T06:26:47+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named django.core.management
2012-03-08T06:26:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-03-08T06:26:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-03-08T06:27:32+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET growing-mountain-9962.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-03-08T06:27:33+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET growing-mountain-9962.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

my requirements.txt file looks like this

```
py-bcrypt==0.2
ipython==0.12
Flask==0.8
django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4
MySQL-python==1.2.3
PIL==1.1.7
South==0.7.3
django-uni-form==0.9.0
django-grappelli
decorator
pytz
babel
django-pagination
bleach
mock
```

and pushing to heroku master is successful

how do i get django.core.management to work on heroku?

Comment: Missing django from requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that I didn't install django on the heroku server.